# Protege: Replace a class with type

Tags: owl, protege

Given an `.owl` file with a lot of information presented not ideally I would like to create a new one without writing down the whole thing.

The main problem is the existence of classes that should be types of a respective attribute. Here's a simplified example:

Imagine we have two classes `University` and `Country` and a relation `hasCountry` between those two. So, we can write

```
Harvard University hasCountry America
Oxford University hasCountry England
```

Now, I would like to create a Country type with possible values all the existing countries and add this new type to every existing university.

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: And now you expect such a rewriting feature in Protege? Either i) use *OWL API* and write a few lines of Java code for conversion, or ii) use a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query with a CLI tool like *Apache Jena* or *RDF4J* - both should work for your example.

Comment: By Country type, do you mean a datatype? This would involve changing all axioms to be datatype assertions, all Country individuals to be literals and hasCountry to be a datatype property.

Comment: If you mean Country as an enumerated type, you just have to define it as such; there is no need to rewrite anything else.

Comment: @AKSW I 'm afraid I know nothing about your ii) option. If you don't mind explain the first in more details.

Comment: @Ignazio can you explain the difference between datatype and enumerated type?(Given that after rewriting the info no new countries will be added. Also, could you suggest a way of implementing your idea(s)?

Comment: OWL API is a Java based API for OWL. It's what Protege also uses to work on OWL ontologies. You have to write a Java class that does the conversion, i.e. remove old axioms and add new axioms.